# Why does this `<Suspense>` child component lose its state rather than render after the suspending promise resolves?

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-lifecycle, react-suspense

In an attempt to understand react's `<Suspense>` component, I'm trying to utilize `setTimeout` to write a simple hook to trigger a "suspended" state for some amount of time before rendering.

In my testing I'm using the following setup:

```js
import { Suspense, useMemo, useState } from "react";

function useSuspend(ms: number) {
  const [isSuspended, setSuspended] = useState(true);
  const promise = useMemo(
    () =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSuspended(false);
          resolve();
        }, ms);
      }),
    [ms]
  );

  console.table({ isSuspended, ms });
  if (isSuspended) {
    throw promise;
  }
}

function Suspending() {
  const [id] = useState(Math.random().toFixed(20));
  console.log(id);

  useSuspend(2500);

  return "Done";
}

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
      <Suspending />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

However, this produces some (to me) rather unexpected log prints:

```
0.91830134558829579206
┌─────────────┬────────┐
│   (index)   │ Values │
├─────────────┼────────┤
│ isSuspended │  true  │
│     ms      │  2500  │
└─────────────┴────────┘

(2.5s pause)

0.33716150767738661820
┌─────────────┬────────┐
│   (index)   │ Values │
├─────────────┼────────┤
│ isSuspended │  true  │
│     ms      │  2500  │
└─────────────┴────────┘

(continues infinitely every 2.5s forever)
```

The text "Done" is never rendered either.

These logs would seem to indicate that the `<Suspending />` component does not retain its state after the `useSuspend` hook completes, prompting the component to render "as if new", which is counter intuitive to me. Could someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: For reference: [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspense-timeout-example-4g7rh?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A6%2C37) example is doing things very similarly to me, though variables are kept in the global scope rather than in `useState`.

Comment: The only place I see the value of `isSuspended` changes is `setSuspended()` call inside the callback hell starting with `useMemo()`. From what I can see from your output, this callback is never called. This has nothing to do with state but more to do with the complexity you added with `useMemo()`, `new Promis()` and `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the callback is indeed called (otherwise you would not receive any output every 2.5s). Also, if you convert `isSuspended` to a variable in the global scope (`let isSuspended`), visual output is as expected. State still seems to be lost though, and the `useSuspend` hook can no longer be re-used in other components.

Comment: `console.table({ isSuspended, ms });` is outside the `useMemo()` call back. I recommend adding `console.log()` inside the `useMemo()` callback, inside the `Promise` callback and inside the `setTimeout()` callback to see if any of those are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These logs would seem to indicate that the `<Suspending />` component does not retain its state after the useSuspend hook completes, prompting the component to render "as if new", which is counter intuitive to me.

That's correct. Suspense is designed so that when it catches a promise it will unmount the child tree and render the fallback (if any) instead. Later, the promise resolves and suspense will once again mount the children. As is typical for newly mounted components, their states will be assigned their initial values (ie, `isSuspended` is `true`), and the `useMemo` runs and creates a new promise. This promise then gets thrown, and the process repeats

Throwing promises for suspense to catch is kinda tricky. You typically need to have some value that exists outside the component which you can synchronously check to see if the asynchronous work has been done. If it hasn't, you then throw a promise which can set that external value and resolve itself. For example:

```
let loaded = false;
let promise = null;

function useSuspend(ms: number) {
  if (!loaded) {
    if (!promise) {
      promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          loaded = true;
          resolve();
        }, ms);
      });
    }
    throw promise;
  }
}
```

Note that since `loaded` is a global variable, every component in your app is sharing it. Whichever component calls `useSuspend` first will start a timeout, and all others will reuse the same promise. If you want different components to have different timeouts, you'll need to create some more complex store of values which match your needs.